# Network Speed when using two switches + wireless router

Tags: internet-speed

With my ISP I am paying for 150 down and 30 up (about to upgrade to 300 down and 30 up) but not getting that at all locations in my house.

I have taken my computer around to different spots and plugged in and get the correct speeds but in my office I am only getting 60 down and 30 up but I can confirm that before the switch in my office it is getting 150/30 and I have tried 3 different switches that I have in my office and all produce the same speed.

Would going through multiple switches degrade performance to this degree?

The network setup is as follows:

1. Cable Modem
2. Wireless Router: [Cradlepoint MBR1400](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00649T9WG)
3. Switch: [Netgear GS108PEv2](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/GS108PEv2.aspx)
4. Wall Plate
5. Switch: [Netgear FS105 Switch](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/FS105.aspx)

I have tried the following switches in places of the #5 and still no change in the Internet speed:

1. [TRENDnet TPE-S44](https://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail?prod=100_TPE-S44)
2. [Linksys EZXS55W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009RKAX6)

Comment: Wireless speed is an entirely different issue than wired speed.   You really have two questions that should be asked seperatly.  If the switches are modern unmanaged switches they wont reduce speed. A bad switch, or and old slower speed switch, or bad cable might.

Comment: generally speaking, a decent switch, especially one that is being lightly used, should not cause a degradation in speed. make sure your switch is half-decent, your cabling is Cat5-E or better, and in good shape.

Comment: I just looked up all the model numbers and device details and it looks like the three of the products I tried are only 10/100lbps where my first switch is a Gigabit switch. So that would be the problem correct?

Comment: that sounds like the issue. replace the 10/100 switch with a gigabit capable one.

Comment: Frank can you post that as the answer so I can accept it? I just purchase new switches and access points to help speed up the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since much of your hardware has a max throughput of 100mbps, it will never be able to reach the full line speed of your Internet service. In general you will only get about 60% of max throughput on standard home-grade commercial networking equipment, getting 60mbps on at least one line is actually pretty good.

So, to sum up, upgrade the 10/100mbps equipment to 1000mbps, and you should enjoy your full Internet Service speed throughout your network.